# How can you use the `Image.core` return from `ImageFont.getmask`?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

The `ImageFont.getmask()` method returns an `Image.core` bitmap.

Every time I try to do any trick to render this bitmap into an image, I get the error

```
AttributeError: 'ImagingCore' object has no attribute 'load'
```

I've tried:

- `image.paste(bitmap, xy)`
- `image.paste(color, xy, bitmap)`
- `image.paste(bitmap.convert('RGBA'), xy)`
- `imagedraw.bitmap(xy, bitmap, color)`

How is it possible to render or make use of the bitmap mask returned from `ImageFont.getmask()`?

---

*Edit*: I am using `Pillow` version `7.1.1` on Python `3.7.2` on Windows 10

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to do this.  Not sure if it's the right way, but this is what I did:

```
# given `bitmap` is an Image.core image, generate an Image that matches it.
    bitmap_image = Image.frombytes(bitmap.mode, bitmap.size, bytes(bitmap))
```

Then use `bitmap_image` instead of the original `bitmap` wherever you need a "real" image object.